# Checking if iTunes widget shows local currency

Tags: wordpress, widget, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have very small favor to ask here and I don't know if this appropriate or not.

What I'm asking as a favor is that would someone take a quick look at my page http://raekwon.gteayy.com/discs-baby and see if the iTunes widget on my wordpress site shows your local currency?

Also if you have iTunes installed (and can be bothered to ) click "view" album to see if it opens up to your standard (local) iTunes store?

PS I do see that there are appropriate tags for my question, so I'm going to go ahead and post this. If I'm wrong in posting here would you please direct me to a suitable stack exchange?

**EDIT** It's working at [Raekwon Discography + Downloads](http://raekwon.gteaay.com/discs-baby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Germany:
Had to disable AdBlock on your page.
Widget shows 65 Kr,
links to https://itunes.apple.com/no/album/only-built-4-cuban-linx/id258634938?ign-mpt=uo%3D4
but iTunes opened in the german store ( €7,99 ).

Comment: So you had to disable Adblock to see the iTunes widget? Was is totally invisible before you disabled Adblock? Also what browser are you using and is Adblock something extra that you have installed or does it come with browser?

Comment: Totally invisible before the AdBlock disable. Safari 7.0.3 on German Mac OS 10.9.2 . Adblock is a plug-in for Safari. https://getadblock.com .